# How to put tags on photos in Windows that WordPress can read and apply on media files?

Tags: plugins, media

I'm creating a Stock Photo gallery on WordPress with PhotoPress Image Taxonomies by Peter Adams and I noticed that when I upload photos from iStockphoto, the taxonomies keyword is filled with tags that it originally have on iStockphoto site. I tried doing this on Windows using the tagging feature on windows photo gallery and also on the properties of the image itself but it doesn't appear like that of the image on iStock photo.

By the way, this is not a commercial project but an internal for the company to use.

So how is iStock photo embedding their keywords on their photo that the plugin by Peter Adams is reading? This will obviously make tagging much easier because when you do tagging on Windows Photo Gallery, you  can do it by bulk that WordPress is not able to do.

Comment: Exif data, I don't know much about it, but came through this http://www.peteradamsphoto.com/?page_id=3148

Comment: Exif data. I think that is the answer. That made me try Lightroom to add tags  into the photos and WordPress actually read it. The only problem now is the other taxonomies. Right now it reads the Keyword taxonomy but I have more like Photo Collections, Photo Country and others which the plugin also provide. Now, how can I add that to Lightroom is the question.

Comment: Are they processed by plugin you are using possibly? From quick look through source [`wp_read_image_metadata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_read_image_metadata/) doesn't seem to process taxonomies.

Comment: I think they are. I am now using lightroom to get all the keywords into the metadata and now WordPress can read it. Thanks!